# How to create composite foreign key in sql server management studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, composite-key

I can successfully create composite primary key in sql server management studio 2012 by selecting two columns (OrderId, CompanyId) and right click and set as primary key. But i don't know how to create foreign key on two columns(OrderId, CompanyId) in other table by using sql server management studio 2012.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Object Explorer, go to your table and select `Keys > New Foreign Key` from the context menu:

[image]

From the dialog box that pops up, click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button to create a new foreign key:

[image]

Give it a meaningful name and then click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button to open the `Tables and Columns specification` dialog box:

[image]

Fill in the necessary columns for the parent and the child tables, click <kbd>OK</kbd> and **you're done!**

Or **much easier and more efficiently** - use a T-SQL script!

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.OtherTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OtherTable_ParentTable
FOREIGN KEY(OrderId, CompanyId) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(OrderId, CompanyId)
```

Comment: I know the above query, but problem is that i want to do it visually. You mentioned foreign key in screenshot. its fine but in case of composite primary foreign key relation it did not mentioned in screenshots......

Comment: @user3004110: if you need to reference a compound primary key, you just have to select more than one column in the dialog to define the foreign key!

Comment: GUI way was not working, T-SQL script worked right away

Answer (score 0):

If you open the submenu for a table in the table list in Management Studio, there is an item `Keys`. If you right-click this, you get `New Foreign Key` as option. If you select this, the Foreign Key Relationships dialogue opens. In the section (General), you will find `Tables And Columns Specifications`. If i open this, i can select multiple columns.

Answer (score -1):

Add two separate foreign keys for each column.

Comment: If there's only a composite primary key on the referenced table, and no other declared keys, you cannot create a foreign key that only references one of the columns.

Comment: is it possible? I don't think so!