# How do I constrain input into this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm trying to build a database thats a little more involved than I've done before - SQL isn't one of my strengths.

I have the following 3 tables:

- A product has rates;
- A product also has product details.

I'm trying to apply 3 constraints without much success and could do with some help - I'm unsure whether I should be using triggers or a combination of FK/constraint/trigger to achieve what I want.

- ProductRate can only contain a single occurance IsPrimary = true per ProductID;
- A ProductDetail row should only be able to define a ProductRate with the same ProductID;
- A Products Details group (defined by the ProductID), should contain at least one occurance of the rate that is defined as primary.

Any advice appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I would highly recommend you not name your identity column ID in every table. Column names changing from table to table is just painful to deal with. Name the columns what it is (ProductID, ProductRateID, ProductDetailID).

Comment: Can you post examples of each of the constraints you want to enforce?   I don't understand some of your plain-English descriptions.

Comment: @TabAlleman - catch 22 Tab - I'm struggling to understand the best approach to each, not to mention how to apply them. If I could provide the information you want, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Well, I mean, if you could post sample data, and say things like, "The second row in Table B should not be allowed because it violates x."   Because for example, I don't understand what you mean by this:  •A ProductDetail row should only be able to define a ProductRate with the same ProductID;

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would handle this.

"A ProductDetail row should only be able to define a ProductRate with the same ProductID;" - This is pretty straight forward. You make the ProductID be a foreign key in ProductDetail.

For the other two requirements I would make a slight change to your table structure. I would add another column to the Product table like PrimaryProductRateID. Make that column not null and have a foreign key to the ProductRate table. That ensures you can only have 1 and it will also be required.

I would not recommend using a trigger for something like this.

Comment: First of a series of questions - apologies for the simple naivity. Can the ProductID be a foreign key in ProductDetail given its not unique?

Comment: FKs don't have to be unique.   PKs have to be unique.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Sorry Tab, I thought an FK had to be linked to a unique constraint in the other table - ProductID isn't unique in ProductRate

Comment: Of course it isn't unique in ProductRate. It should be a foreign key which means that any value of ProductID in the ProductRate table must exist in the Product table.

Comment: Ah, now I finally understand your requirement.   In that case, Sean's solution won't work.   Sean, he needs to limit ProductID-ProductRateID in Table ProductDetail to combinations that also exist in Table ProductRate.   @dotnetnoob if the combination of ProductID and ProductRateID is unique in Table ProductRate, and I guess it must be if ProductRateID is the PK, then you can make an alternate Unique Key on those two columns, and link the FK to that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059880/how-to-create-composite-foreign-key-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012

Comment: @TabAlleman in that case wouldn't it make more sense to just have the ProductDetail table have a foreign key to the ProductRate table? Then remove ProductID from ProductDetail entirely. Then each Product can have any number of ProductRates and each rate can have any number of ProductDetails. Or maybe there is something else I am not quite seeing.

Comment: The way his tables are set up now, a product has 1 or more rates.   A product also has 1 or more details, and each detail is associated with a rate.  What needs to be enforced is that the detail's rate must be one that is associated with that detail's product.  But yes, since a Rate can only have one Product, there is no need for ProductID in the ProductDetail table.   The ProductID can be inferred from the ProductRate.

Comment: @SeanLange - I see where you're coming from - thats something I considered but it just felt wrong from a structural perspective - a product has details, rates dont have details

Comment: I should also throw something else in 'Entity Framework' - this means traversing through rates to details, which again feels wrong.

Comment: Sort of sounds to me like a product has rates and each rate has details but I could be wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange - a product has details (think of it as an order line) has a rate. To avoid duplication, rates are abstracted out into their own table.

Comment: So then does the rate belong to the detail? Or this is a two way many:many?

Comment: @SeanLange - yes - instead of product detail think 'order line' that has Tax rate, so each order line may have the same rate, but on some order lines  the tax rate might be zero or exempt. Instead of product think supplier - my supplier operates in a country where only certain rates are available.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case I would think an extra table would make this work. It would contain 3 columns (ProductID, ProductDetailID and ProductRateID). Make those 3 columns a composite primary key. Does something like that make sense?